Does camel support transaction for Kafka consumers?
Need to have transaction route reading from kafka->persit in db-> publish to MQ.
all of this should happen in one transaction if DB or Commit to MQ/JMS fails then kafka message should not be removed from topic.
Tried to lookup camel docs but havent found any use case . https://camel.apache.org/components/4.4.x/eips/transactional-client.html

See the camel-kafka docs there is a section on transactions at:
https://camel.apache.org/components/4.4.x/kafka-component.html#_kafka_transaction
